# several key value for post http request vs one key and json value

Tags: json, node.js, http, web, request

I would like to know which way is standard and normal.
I send a post http request with a lot of key and value pairs but I can send only one key and a json string object as a value. Which is more suitable
Thx

Comment: what back ed techno do you use ? I use C# .NET

Comment: node js back ed techno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on your backend : if it receives an object then use the second option {"myParamName:{"prop1":prop1,"prop2":prop2}}
If it receives several params then use option one

In my option use json syntax and send an object to the back : sending several params is good when you've got a few but what would you do when you need to send dozens ?

edit : As I see in your profile you use C# here is an example of ajax query to a .NET WEB METHOD :

```
$("#save").on('click', function (event) {
    // setting the object of the back-end
    var obj = {};
    obj.Description = $("#Description").val().trim();
    obj.Reference = $("#Reference").val().trim();
    obj.Duration = $("#Duration").val();
    obj.Begin = $("#Begin").val();
    obj.End = $("#End").val();
    obj.Id = $("#Id").val();
    obj.Notes = $("#Notes").val().replace(/[\n\r]/g, '<br>');
    obj.Done = $("#Done").val() == "true" ? true : false;
    // to json format
    var json = JSON.stringify({ "toDo": obj });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Main.aspx/AddWork",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: json,
        success: function (response) {
            // do what ever you want
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var str = jqXHR.responseText;
            var obj = JSON.parse(str);
            console.log(obj.Message);
        } // end error
    }); // end ajax
});


// on the back end : we receive an object named toDo of type Data
[WebMethod]
public static void AddWork(Data toDo)
{
...
}

// the Data type is declared in the same web method :
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Begin { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public int? Duration { get; set; }
    public bool? Done { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

}

// Hope it helps
```

Comment: thx yes I have a lot of fields.
note: I want to implement a backend server

Comment: What back-end techno will you use then ?

Comment: And will you use plain javascript, jquery ? I can give you examples in jquery if you provide an example of your code

Comment: I use unity for front end (game) and nodejs backend server
I want to send http post request

Comment: unfortunatly I don't know node.js :-( and neither unity you should have explain better

Comment: my question was not about languages and environments! it was about post http request that is the same for all of them.
My data have json formats and contain a lot of fields so I think it is better to use one key and json format for value (key/value pair post request) Thx

Comment: OK you are right I tend to be pratical. Hope it helped you anyway. Good game making ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Standard and normal is to just send plain `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data. This approach has existed since long before JSON was designed and you can generate `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data with a plain HTML form submission.

Encoding your data as `application/json` and then embedding it inside `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` creates more work to encode and decode the data, and adds more possible points of failure.

The only advantage that JSON offers is that it has native support for more complex data structures like arrays and objects… but extensions to the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (supported by (at least) PHP, [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions), and [PHP::ParseStr](https://metacpan.org/pod/PHP::ParseStr)) add that.

The option you didn't mention was just plain `application/json` which is popular with HTTP based APIs. It doesn't have the advantage of being compatible with a plain HTML form submission, but it doesn't have the complexity of embedding the two formats.